# JOGL Canvas cover other SWT Widgets

Tags: opengl, swt, jogl

I am an amatuer with JOGL and SWT. I got a problem while try show some SWT Widgets over the GLCanvas using AbsoluteLayout.

```
composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(null);
Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
button.setText("New Button");
button.setBounds(172, 145, 94, 28);
glcanvas = GLCanvas.create(composite, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND, null, null, null);
```

I thought that the button should be on top of GLCanvas but it is always behind the GLCanvas. Am i doing something wrong ? Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(null);
glcanvas = GLCanvas.create(composite, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND, null, null, null);
Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
button.setText("New Button");
button.setBounds(172, 145, 94, 28);
```

(Moving the glcanvas = GLCanvas... upwards to before creating the button)

Unless I'm missing something you're adding the button and then the canvas on top of it.

Comment: I changed the order as you suggested but the GLCanvas still cover the button! I don't know why, i am trying to dig into the source code of JOGL GLCanvas.

Comment: [Here](http://forum.jogamp.org/Can-I-put-awt-components-over-part-of-a-GLCanvas-td827759.html) is a discussion about placing AWT components on top of a GLCanvas. What OS are you running?

Comment: I am developing under MacOS (10.8.4). I have read that topic but i am not trying to place a components on top of GLCanvas. I just try to add  GLCanvas into a AbsoluteLayout, but it did not work :(

Comment: If you're trying to place SWT components side by side with GLCanvas, that should not be a problem. In this case it looks like you set the absolute position of the button, but not of the canvas. I would assume that the canvas then takes up the whole space and due to the bug on OS X, the button is not rendered on top of it. Try setting the position and dimenstions of the canvas too.

Comment: For more on AWT/SWING + JOGL check out my old game toolkit on [Github](https://github.com/JBarberU/Medioqre-Toolkit-V3/blob/master/src/toolkit/tilemapeditor/TileMapEditor.java). You may also checkout the actual game it was used for [Github](https://github.com/johanbrook/medioqre).

Comment: I tried to set the position and dimensions of the canvas too. But it still doesn't work.The other layout manager work correctly. Whatever thank you very much for your support, it may be feel more confident!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no solution for this problem. For more details, this problem only happens on MacOS , i have tested under Windows 8 x64 and it ok no thing is overlayed. Here is the link to the discusion on the official forum 
http://forum.jogamp.org/How-to-overlay-SWT-Widgets-over-GLCanvas-td4029507.html